# iOS - Sqlite store as `DATE` or `day`, `month`, `year`?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, date, group-by

I want to generate monthly & yearly report eventually.

Let say I have a table **transaction** which consists of *(price, date, ...)*, I want to generate a report which **group by** `month`.

Should I store the date as 3 separate fields **day**, **month**, and **year**? Or I can store it as **date** with `Date` data type?

If **date**, how is the query look like and how to implement it in iOS?

**NOTE: I'm new to iOS**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In databases, you should always want to store dates as dates, not as their component fields.

SQLite provides various functions for manipulating and ordering dates, so you can use them.

Getting the month out of a date is quite easy.

Use the `date`.